# Android Java Sharedpreferences won't save data

Tags: java, android, save, sharedpreferences, saving-data

After I "saved" a String it will return (in my case) "error":
 **html_value1 is not ""**

**MainActivity:**

```
  tools.getEditor(tools.getPreferences(getApplicationContext())).putString("wochea9a", html_value1);
tools.getEditor(tools.getPreferences(getApplicationContext())).putString("wocheb9a", html_value2);
tools.getEditor(tools.getPreferences(getApplicationContext())).commit();
```

**Alarmserviceactivity:**

```
   savedwochea9a =   tools.getPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("wochea9a", "error");
        savedwocheb9a = tools.getPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("wocheb9a", "error");
```

**tools:**

```
public class tools {


    static SharedPreferences preferences;
  static  SharedPreferences.Editor editor;




    public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context){
        preferences  =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return  preferences;
    }
    public static SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(SharedPreferences preferences){
        editor  = preferences.edit();

        return  editor;
    }
...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you create an editor (using `edit()`) you have to call either `commit()` or `apply()` in order for the results to be saved.

So, your code should look like this:

**MainActivity:**

```
tools.getEditor(tools.getPreferences(getApplicationContext()))
  .putString("wochea9a", html_value1)
  .putString("wocheb9a", html_value2)
  .commit(); // or .apply();
```

Even better if you use `apply()`. This method returns straight away, saving the data in the background without blocking the thread.